# Chrome popup window always on top

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome app that opens a popup window. I would like it to be able to stay on top, but am currently unable to do so.

The [Chat for Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd) extension opens a popup window that not only stays on top of all windows, but the window itself also appears to have a completely customized appearance. Unfortunately, all the JavaScript in this extension is obfuscated, and I can't make heads or tails of it.

The [Chrome API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html) lists the "alwaysOnTop" boolean as part of the Window type, but neither the create nor the update functions allow for changing this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a `panel` type of window. Call [chrome.windows.create](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create) with a `type: 'panel'` parameter. This currently only works in the dev and canary channels.

Comment: This can be found in the obfuscated code : `chrome.windows.create({type:"panel",focused:c,width:d.width,height:d.height,url:a});` (in ace-extension.js, with a similar one in ace-datachannels.js)

Comment: It's worth noting that I seem to require the "--enable-panels" option enabled when I start Chrome, otherwise it will just create a popup window.

The Chat extension seems to create a panel even without the option enabled, but I don't know if that's some special magic because it's Google, or what.

Comment: Correct. The flag must be enabled, or you must use the dev or canary channel, or the extension ID must be hardcoded in `chrome/browser/ui/panels/panel_manager.cc`.

Comment: Do we have a timeline of when panels are going to be available to the developpers?

Comment: They must be using some undocumented API for the talk extension. It works without the -enable-panels