# experimental chrome history extension

Tags: css, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I wanted to make a chrome extension that acted as a veil over the browser window. The more the user visited a websites the more filled a the veil would be with their history.  I have looked at some chrome extensions, but they all seem linked to an icon and every time you visit a new site the pop up disappears.  A icon based solution would be fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to keep the box up and how to make the box transparent(no white background, just text).  The sample extension I was messing with can be found here...

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/history/showHistory.zip

here is some of the code I am missing with now.  I am able to throw a div over the browser, but when I try to combine the extension from above's code things go awry...I am not extremely fluent beyond basic js and processing, but I don't see anything wrong or contradictory...Advice?

content.js

```
   function createHistoryDiv() {
    var divHeight = 97;
    var divMargin = 10;

    var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "history";
    var st = div.style;
    st.display = "block";
    st.zIndex = "10000000";
    st.top = "0px";
    st.left = "0px";
    st.right = "0px";
    st.height = divHeight + "%";
    st.background = "rgba(255, 255, 255, .01)";
    st.margin = divMargin + "px";
    st.padding = "5px";
    st.border = "5px solid black";
    st.color = "black";
        st.fontFamily = "Arial,sans-serif";     
        st.fontSize = "36";
    st.position = "fixed";
    st.overflow = "hidden";
    st.boxSizing = "border-box";
        st.pointerEvents = "none";

    document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
    var heightInPixels = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(div).height);
    st.height = heightInPixels + 'px';
    //document.body.style.webkitTransform = "translateY("
            //+ (heightInPixels + (2 * divMargin))+ "px)";

    return div;
}

function buildDivContent(historyDiv, data) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    historyDiv.appendChild(ul);

    for (var i = 0, ie = data.length; i < ie; ++i) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = data[i];
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]));

        var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.style.color = "black";
                li.style.display = "inline";
                li.style.wordBreak = "break all";
        li.appendChild(a);
                a.style.color = "black";
                a.style.fontSize = "24px";
                a.style.linkDecoration = "none";
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "buildTypedUrlList" }, function(data) {
    var historyDiv = createHistoryDiv();
    buildDivContent(historyDiv, data);
});

function logoDiv(){
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.id = "logo";
        var st = div2.style;
    st.display = "block";
    st.zIndex = "10000001";
    st.bottom = "0px";
    //st.left = "0px";
    st.right = "0px";
    st.height = "42px";
        st.width = "210px";
    st.background = "rgba(255, 255, 255,1)";
    st.padding = "5px";
        st.margin = "10px";
    st.border = "5px solid black";
    st.color = "black";
        st.fontFamily = "Arial,sans-serif";     
    st.position = "fixed";
    st.overflow = "hidden";
    st.boxSizing = "border-box";
        //st.pointerEvents = "none";

            document.documentElement.appendChild(div2);
                div2.innerHTML = div2.innerHTML + "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"toggle_visibility(\"logo\");\" style = \"display:block;font-size:24px;margin:0;padding:0;color: black;\">TRANSPARENCY</a>";
                                             return div2;
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById("logo");
       if(e.style.display == "block")
          e.style.display = "hidden";
       else
          e.style.display = "block";
    }

}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "buildTypedUrlList" }, function(data){

    var titleDiv = logoDiv();
    buildDivContent(titleDiv);
});
```

Comment: Define _"awry"_, please !

Comment: sorry...vagueness isn't exactly best policy when you want solutions.

Comment: when I say awry, I mean when the code snippets are put together neither or them fucntion.  The div I created with a border disappears and the history thats supposed to be pulled is not

Comment: You never append the code to the created div (unless you do it inside `buildPopupDom()`, which you don't provide, so I can't tell).

Comment: It turned out the problems with your code were deeper - please, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You have really messed things up while merging the two pieces of code, resulting in a non-functional content-script.
2. You are trying to access the `history` API from the context of a content-script, but it is only available to the background-page (or any extension view for that matter). One solution is to communicate between the content-script and the background-page through **[Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)**.

Below is the source code of a sample extension that takes care of both problems:

**mannifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_idle",
        "all_frames": false
    }],

    "permissions": [
        "history"
    ]
}
```

**background.js:**

```
// Search history to find up to ten links that a user has typed in,
// and show those links in a popup.
function buildTypedUrlList(callback) {
  // To look for history items visited in the last week,
  // subtract a week of microseconds from the current time.
  var millisecondsPerWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date().getTime() - millisecondsPerWeek;

  // Track the number of callbacks from chrome.history.getVisits()
  // that we expect to get.  When it reaches zero, we have all results.
  var numRequestsOutstanding = 0;

  chrome.history.search({
      'text': '',              // Return every history item....
      'startTime': oneWeekAgo  // that was accessed less than one week ago.
    },
    function(historyItems) {
      // For each history item, get details on all visits.
      for (var i = 0; i < historyItems.length; ++i) {
        var url = historyItems[i].url;
        var processVisitsWithUrl = function(url) {
          // We need the url of the visited item to process the visit.
          // Use a closure to bind the  url into the callback's args.
          return function(visitItems) {
            processVisits(url, visitItems);
          };
        };
        numRequestsOutstanding++;
        chrome.history.getVisits({url: url}, processVisitsWithUrl(url));
      }
      if (!numRequestsOutstanding) {
        onAllVisitsProcessed();
      }
    });


  // Maps URLs to a count of the number of times the user typed that URL into
  // the omnibox.
  var urlToCount = {};

  // Callback for chrome.history.getVisits().  Counts the number of
  // times a user visited a URL by typing the address.
  var processVisits = function(url, visitItems) {
    for (var i = 0, ie = visitItems.length; i < ie; ++i) {
      // Ignore items unless the user typed the URL.
      if (visitItems[i].transition != 'typed') {   // <-- modify to allow different
                                                   //     types of transitions
        continue;
      }

      if (!urlToCount[url]) {
        urlToCount[url] = 0;
      }

      urlToCount[url]++;
    }

    // If this is the final outstanding call to processVisits(),
    // then we have the final results.  Use them to build the list
    // of URLs to show in the popup.
    if (!--numRequestsOutstanding) {
      onAllVisitsProcessed();
    }
  };

  // This function is called when we have the final list of URls to display.
  var onAllVisitsProcessed = function() {
    // Get the top scorring urls.
    urlArray = [];
    for (var url in urlToCount) {
      urlArray.push(url);
    }

    // Sort the URLs by the number of times the user typed them.
    urlArray.sort(function(a, b) {
      return urlToCount[b] - urlToCount[a];
    });

    callback(urlArray.slice(0, 10));
  };
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, callback) {
    if (msg.action === 'buildTypedUrlList') {
        buildTypedUrlList(callback);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

**content.js:**

```
function createHistoryDiv() {
    var divHeight = 25;
    var divMargin = 10;

    var div = document.createElement("div");

    var st = div.style;
    st.display = "block";
    st.zIndex = "10";
    st.top = "0px";
    st.left = "0px";
    st.right = "0px";
    st.height = divHeight + "%";
    st.background = "rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)";
    st.margin = divMargin + "px";
    st.padding = "5px";
    st.border = "5px solid black";
    st.color = "black";
    st.fontFamily = "Arial, sans-serif";
    st.fontStyle = "bold";
    st.position = "fixed";
    st.overflow = 'auto';
    st.boxSizing = "border-box";

    document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
    var heightInPixels = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(div).height);
    st.height = heightInPixels + 'px';
    document.body.style.webkitTransform = "translateY("
            + (heightInPixels + (2 * divMargin))+ "px)";

    return div;
}

function buildDivContent(historyDiv, data) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    historyDiv.appendChild(ul);

    for (var i = 0, ie = data.length; i < ie; ++i) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = data[i];
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]));

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(a);

        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "buildTypedUrlList" }, function(data) {
    var historyDiv = createHistoryDiv();
    buildDivContent(historyDiv, data);
});
```

Comment: this has solved all my problems, thank you.  I modifies the code to display a live stream of the history, which is exactly what I wanted, but not all the history being placed in the div seems to be styled by the current webpages css and all attempts to style it myself are ignored like for instance formating the color of text in the div or the link decorations.  Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried styling the `<li>` and `<a>` elements directly ? I.e. when creating each element: `li.style.color = ...` etc (the same way you style your div). If you really want to stay unaffected by the page's CSS, you can look into `Shadow DOM` (google it), but it ain't going to be an easy road...

Comment: SOLVED!  I tried styling the div, the ul, and the li, but what I needed to style was the actual anchor elements.  ExpertSystem, I'm extremely indebted to you.  What would be some good sources to read to get more of a command on this stuff, any suggestions?

Comment: Always glad to help ! If you think it is helpful and worth it you can also upvote my answer ;)

Comment: So one last thing and the project will be complete...I have added another div on top, sortof like a "logo" that contains a div with a link...I want this link to be able to toggle the "history" div on and off, but can't seem to get it to work...I tried having it toogle another div and that wouldnt work either.  Look at the edit of my original post above for the updated content.js script.  Right now its setup to toggle the logo div onclick, but it does nothing.  I don't know if its a scope issue or even syntax...thanks

Comment: It is not a good practice to change the question kike this because it will render the answers irrelevant and confuse future visitors. It is not supposed to be a per project question that evolves along with the project. Rather one question should refer to a single issue. I suggest you rollback the changes and post a new question regarding the (new) toggling issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post that answers your question:
[Chrome popup window always on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039613/chrome-popup-window-always-on-top)

Food for thought:
You could use a content script to programmatically inject a transparent div over site content and put your history information in there. It's more work than the above answer but hey, it might be fun :)

Edit:

So I the 'always on top' solution and I don't think it's quite what you're looking for. It creates a popup unless your browser is started with a `--enable-panels` flag.

It looks like to get exactly what you're looking for you will have to use the content script method I mentioned above.

Comment: The `panel` thingy will not work unless explicitely enabled by the user (in stable channel at least). But +1 for the second suggestion. It is 100% doable, not that hard and lots of fun :)

Comment: A **[short example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093066/how-to-insert-iframe-div-to-the-top-of-browser-body-in-javascript-in-chrome-exte)** on how to create a horizontal toolbar using a content script. In a very similar fashion, one could create an informational, transparent div (or whatever).